# Python: lxml with xpath return blank

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I just want the name of the title tag. It looks simple but my result return blank. I am trying to get "ABM FUJIYA BERHAD [S] (5198) | Bursa Malaysia Market" from the link

```
<title>ABM FUJIYA BERHAD [S] (5198) | Bursa Malaysia Market</title>
```

Below is my code

```
from lxml import html

import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/list-of-companies/plc-profile.html?stock_code=5198')

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

tree1 = tree.xpath('.//title/text()')


>>> tree1
[]
```

I try

```
tree1 = tree.xpath('//title/text()')
```

return same result.
`tree.findtext('.//title')` return blank as well.

I am really curious how I can scrape the data

Comment: there is no `title` tag on that page - the DOM is manipulated with JS after it loads, so `lxml` won't see it

Comment: @KeithHall, how can I get the data in this case?

Comment: After a quick google search, I found this guide about getting data from js generated pages: https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/